# С чего начать изучать QT?

Tags: c++, qt

Установил qt creator под виндой c базой на QT 4.8.2. Скачал книгу Бланшет, Саммерфилд "QT4 Программирование GUI на С++" (2ed) и теперь понял, что архитектура описанная в книге отличается от моей версии QT. Как правильно начать изучать QT, чтоб было просто и без последствий? И сразу просьба отправлять только на русские доки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, стоит-таки использовать не 4.8, а более новую ветку 5.* (ей уже года 2), там в частности основным GUI-фреймворком служит qml, а не qwidgets. Ну может не основным, но в 4 был именно qwidgets + в последних версиях появился qml, при этом порты qt на мобильные девайсы работали с qwidgets со скрипом. Что касается книг даже не знаю - я учил когда-то по книге Шлее она простовата, но мне нужно было только немного уложить в голове концепции qt (сигналы-слоты, мок объекты и т.п.), но она тоже по 4.8, есть ли книги по 5 даже не знаю

Ну и QT это все-таки в основном QuickTime, а библиотека обычно пишется qt

Comment: в том то и дело, что у меня машина старенькая и тянет только windows xp, и я нашел только эту нормально работающую сборку Qt + Qt creator, но за ответ благодарствую

Comment: не qt, а Qt.

Comment: спасибо за поправку @KoVadim

Comment: Я и qt видел где-то у них на сайте, но не буду спорить. Главное, что не QT

Answer (score 2):

Есть книга:

```
Шлее М. - Профессиональное программирование на C++. Qt 4.8
```

Как раз под вашу версию, если не найдёте, могу вечерком выложить.

Comment: @mks спасибо, я ее уже читаю.